# CDN serving private images / videos

Tags: database, security, media, cdn

I would like to know how do CDNs serve private data - images / videos. I came across [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580046/serve-protected-assets-through-cdn?rq=1) but this seems to be Amazon CloudFront specific answer.

As a popular example case lets say the problem in question is serving contents inside of facebook. So there is access controlled stuff at an individual user level and also at a group of users level. Besides, there is some publicly accessible data.

All logic of what can be served to whom resides on the server!

Comment: My question would be, is using a CDN for Private/User specific images a best practice? As   
@ShashiPrashanth points out in an answer below, just cache any user images on the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work - all requests first come to the main application server. After determining whether access is allowed or not, a redirect to the CDN server or access-denied error can be shown.

Answer (score 4):

The first request to CDN will go to application server and gets validated for access rights. But there is a catch - keep this in mind:
            Assume that first request is successful and after that, anyone will be able to access the image with that CDN URL. I tested this with Facebook user uploaded restricted image and it was accessible with the CDN URL by others too even after me logging out. So, the image will be accessible till the CDN cache expiry time.

Comment: How about this - <img src="some_img"/>, on your server "some_img" route is redirected to the CDN only after authentication. So the real url is never visible on front end.

Comment: You can do that to add authentication layer in front of CDN. But it will add latency as it is an extra work before accessing CDN.  CDN is used for faster access as data is stored in the nearest data center from user access location.    As URL will be pointing to your app server, you can even consider building logic similar to CDN where you can store that image in your app server file system on 1st call after validation and then from 2nd call onwards, validate and read from your app server filesystem directly and no need to go to your backend to retrieve.

Comment: My question would be, is using a CDN for Private/User specific images a best practice? As   
@ShashiPrashanth points out in an answer below, just cache any user images on the webserver.

Answer (score -1):

Each CDN working differently, so unless you specify which CDN you are looking for its hard to tell.